# Opening CSV file into Google Sheets has certain lines being merged into a single cell

Tags: csv, google-sheets

I have a webscraper creating an index of links and attributes that is outputting to csv, with the intent of opening it up in Google Sheets and using Filter Views to sort and search through it.

However when I open the csv in Sheets, groups of lines are being stuck into a single cell [image: as shown here].

I have shared a test file that demonstrates my problem and gives me the result in the image [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WB2PZ1vyuarBSzjETkbWmn744ZC41Ps8/view?usp=sharing)

I also tried opening it with LibreOffice and got the same result.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I cannot understand about `Here is a link to some of the lines from the file that give the end result https://justpaste.it/9ojxf`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail information for replicating your issue?

Comment: I have changed the the link to point to a .csv file that demonstrates the issue. When I open it in Google Sheets it merges lines into a single cell. If opened in a text editor it displays 29 lines

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have an error in the CSV. If you simply add the right double quotes (as you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/aborruso/88f5252ac6d7bf83191f02e07de46c75/revisions)), you will have no problem in any spreadsheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your CSV data, I noticed that at 6th row which has `A Single Phone Call`, `"` is not closed. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. In this case, when the CSV data is retrieved using `IMPORTDATA`, I confirmed the same issue with your situation.

But, I confirmed that when `Utilities.parseCsv()` of Google Apps Script is used, your CSV data could be correctly parsed. So how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample, the Google Apps Script is used as the custom function. In this case, please use the file ID of the CSV file. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and put the custom function of `=SAMPLE("1WB2PZ1vyuarBSzjETkbWmn744ZC41Ps8")` to a cell. `1WB2PZ1vyuarBSzjETkbWmn744ZC41Ps8` is the file ID of your sample CSV file.

```
const SAMPLE = fileId => Utilities
  .parseCsv(
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${fileId}`).getContentText()
  );
```

- If you want to directly retrieve the CSV data from an URL, you can also the following script.

  ```
    const SAMPLE = url => Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
  ```

Result:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample, the Google Apps Script is run with the script editor. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set the variables, and then, please run `myFunction`. By this, the CSV data is parsed and put to the Spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const id = "1WB2PZ1vyuarBSzjETkbWmn744ZC41Ps8";  // This is the file ID of your sample CSV file.
  
  // 1. Retrieve CSV data.
  const csv = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString();

  // 2. Parse CSV data to an array.
  const ar = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  
  // 3. Put the array to the Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}
```

- This sample script is the same result with above one.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)

Comment: Thanks, I did appreciate the detail you went into, but is was a more complicated answer than I needed. I changed my script to detect if there was an unmatched quote and if so to add one to the end. Yours is probably the more correct way to do it but I have no experience with Google Scripts

Comment: @kingOfSpace Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my answer was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I would like to study more. I think that my answer might be useful for other users. So I would like to leave this.